# Reorganizing divs vertically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 divs going vertically down a page.

I want to be able to click any one, and have it move to be the first div in the order, the top of the "list" in a way. In a perfect world, the others would dim/decrease opacity and the clicked one would slide/animate up to the top while the others bumped down. But, that can come later. I've seen div-reordering done with CSS, but that's not continuously dynamic on the page.

I tried putting all 5 divs inside a container wrapper and doing this in css:

`#wrapper   { display: table; }`

with this javascript (example for clicking second div):

```
$('#secondDiv').css("display","table-header-group");
$('#firstDiv').css("display","table-row-group");
$('#thirdDiv').css("display","table-row-group");
$('#fourthDiv').css("display","table-row-group");
$('#fifthDiv').css("display","table-row-group");
```

but that messed up my rounded corners on the div, my alignment, and other parts of my existing css.

This seems like it shouldn't be that hard, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple solution: move the element to the top using jQuery's `prepend()` to the parent element.

```js
$("div").click(function() {    
    $(this).parent().prepend($(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Div1</div>
<div>Div2</div>
<div>Div3</div>
<div>Div4</div>
<div>Div5</div>
<div>Div6</div>
<div>Div7</div>
<div>Div8</div>
<div>Div9</div>
<div>Div10</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.reorderable').click(function(){
  $(this).prependTo(this.parentNode);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="reorderable">first</div>
  <div class="reorderable">second</div>
  <div class="reorderable">third</div>
  <div class="reorderable">fourth</div>
  <div class="reorderable">fifth</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [jQuery UI tools that enable sortable displays](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

Your end goal seems to be consistent with this jQuery UI feature.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. Please add a code example to explain what you mean.